# How to fix a div inside bootstrap slide Menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Iam trying to fix a div always on top in slide menu.scroll needs only for the bellow contents how can i fix this issue? please check my fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/kannankds/j79hggn3/

```
<div id="wrapper">
<!-- Sidebar -->
   <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
      <div class="topHead"> <!--need to fix this area-->
        <input type="text"><input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="ok">
     </div> <!--area ends-->     
     <ul>
        <li>menu1</li>
        <li>menu1</li>
        <li>menu1</li>
        <li>menu1</li>
        <li>menu1</li>
        <li>menu1</li>
        <li>menu1</li>
        <li>menu1</li>
        <li>menu1</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
<!-- Page content -->
 <div id="page-content-wrapper">
   <div class="content-header">
     <h1 id="home">
       <a id="menu-toggle" href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify btn-menu toggle">
       <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
       </a>
    </h1>
   </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kannankds/j79hggn3/

Comment: So you want the hamburger to be always at the top right and never to shift from that position?

Comment: Give height to your ul menu .. maybe like height:calc(100% - height of top head) and add scroll

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/t7w3u4ep/

Answer (score 0):

```
  #sidebar-wrapper .topHead{
       position: absolute;
       top: 0;
   }
   #sidebar-wrapper ul{
      margin:0px;
      padding-top:50px;
      overflow: auto;
      height: 100%;
    }
```

use absolute position  for sidebar top head and set height to the ul and add overflow scroll to the menu items conatiner ul .Check if it works https://jsfiddle.net/31ndd6kk/4/

Comment: fixed height is not possible. iam trying auto height for dynamic elements.based on the screen size scroll needs to reduse

Comment: you can use calc function in css or set the height of sidebar content using javascript. height : calc(100vh - 50px)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="wrapper">
<!-- Sideba][1]r -->

<div class="topHead"> <!--need to fix this area-->
<input type="text"><input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="ok">
</div> <!--area ends--> 

<!--//// Do as follow ////

1. add your scroll to id 'sidebar-wrapper' 
2. set the height to 'sidebar-wrapper'
-->
<div id="sidebar-wrapper">   
    <ul>
    <li>menu1</li>
      ...
    </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- Page content -->
    <div id="page-content-wrapper">
    <div class="content-header">
    <h1 id="home">
    <a id="menu-toggle" href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify btn-menu toggle">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
    </h1>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: your fiddle not loading.

Answer (score 0):

Check this Updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/j79hggn3/2/)

Changes in CSS:

```
#sidebar-wrapper ul {
  height: calc(100% - 34px);
  overflow: auto;
}
#wrapper.active {
  position: absolute;
  left: 250px;
}
```

Note: comment or remove the `#sidebar-wrapper` style `overflow-y: auto`.